# I get All NFTs ID when I only should get the one that belong to the current account

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ethereum, blockchain

I get All NFTs token ID when I only should get the one that belongs to the current account.
I'm Also getting the token ID for the current account but also all the other Tokens ID.

How do i resolve this ?
This is the code

```
const { enableWeb3, account, isWeb3Enabled, Moralis, deactivateWeb3 } = useMoralis();

useEffect(() => {
  if(isWeb3Enabled) return 
  if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
      if(window.localStorage.getItem('connected')){
          enableWeb3();
      }
  }
}, [isWeb3Enabled])


useEffect(() => {
  Moralis.onAccountChanged((account) => {
      if(account == null){
          window.localStorage.removeItem('connected')
          deactivateWeb3();
      }
  })
}, [])
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://dxt.dexit.network"));

const contractAddress = "0x075D8f52dC5B1F35005dBa8Db40734CBcaBEbd8F"; // replace with the actual contract address
const abi = require('../abi.json'); // replace with the actual ABI of the contract

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi.abi, contractAddress);

async function getNFTs(address) {
  const events = await contract.getPastEvents("Transfer", {
    filter: { to: address },
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: "latest"
  });
  return events.map(event => event.returnValues.tokenId);
  
}


const test2 = async () => {
  console.log(await getNFTs(account));
}

test2();
```

This is the result [As you can see i get all NFTs but I only want token ID 45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0brZv.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
return events.map(event => event.returnValues.tokenId);
```

you are mapping all the events that have `returnValues.tokenId` truthy. That means if `returnValues.tokenId`has any value you will map them into the new array. This is the logic of `.map` in javascript, you are mapping all the elements that satisfy the given condition.

You are most likely emitting an event when you create an NFT.

```
event NftItemCreated(
        // you have returnValues
        // I dont know what  ReturnValuesStruct is, maybe you have address recorded here
        ReturnValuesStruct returnValues,
        // you should also add this field 
        address creator,
    );
```

Now you will be logging the creator address of the NFT. Then you should write this logic

```
async function getNFTs(address) {
  const events = await contract.getPastEvents("Transfer", {
    filter: { to: address },
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: "latest"
  });
  const addressNfts=events.map((event)=>{
     if (event.creator===address){
        return event.returnValues.tokenId
     }
})
  return addressNfts
  
}
```